# Converting voxelized model into smooth form

Tags: graphics, 3d, computational-geometry, voxel, 3d-modelling

I have a 3D model as mesh structure or in .stl/.obj format which I converted to voxels using [binvox](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~min/binvox/) voxelization tool. Using a Java program, I have done some processing on the voxel grid thus obtained. Now, I wish to covert this voxelized model back into a "smooth" mesh  structure (or any other format), which can later be exported to .stl or .obj format.

Can someone suggest how can I achieve the last part, i.e. converting the voxel grid into some format for retrieving back the "smooth" surfaces ? Any help, including pointing to existing tools, or relevant theory in this direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to Marching Cubes algorithm. See http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/ for more details.

Comment: Marching Cubes requires that you know the values of a scalar field on every vertex. This information is probably lost after voxelization.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You don't need a value on every vertex but on every grid point, which is basically a voxel value.

Comment: marching cubes uses the scalar field/ ISO value to determine where on each edge the triangle vertices are, they can be halfway on every edge of a marching cube. voxels can use marching cubes, but the scalar field is always 1/0 which makes it blocky. it works though.